# How adding items to an OptionGroup using declarative method in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, items

I'm newer in vaadin, and I want to know how can I add items to an optionGroup component using vaadin declarative method.

I tried that by it didn't work

```
<v-select-optiongroup id="evaluation" caption="Evaluation" items="sophia,kata" />
```

I need your help please

Comment: `items = "sophia,kata,......."` seems simple for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<v-option-group> 
  <option>Option 1</option> 
  <option>Option 2</option> 
  <option>Option 3</option> 
</v-option-group>
```